# MSSQL: Select rows with more than 2 occurrences in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I need to get a list of CampaignTitles that have more than 2 occurrences in StaffOnGrade and list the CampaignTitle, StaffNo who have a Grade rating higher then 2

WorksOn table:

```
CampaignTitle      | StaffNo
-------------------|--------
ADVENTURE WORLD    | 11
AIR CANADA         | 11
CARNIVAL CRUISES   | 3
CARNIVAL CRUISES   | 8
CARNIVAL CRUISES   | 9
FLIGHT CENTRE      | 7
FLIGHT CENTRE      | 10
HARVEYWORLD TRAVEL | 4
LAST MINUTE        | 4
PRINCESS CRUISES   | 3
PRINCESS CRUISES   | 5
PRINCESS CRUISES   | 6
PRINCESS CRUISES   | 7
PRINCESS CRUISES   | 11
TRAVELSCENE        | 10
VALUETOURS AUST    | 3
VIRGIN AUSTRALIA   | 10
```

StaffOnGrade table:

```
Grade | StaffNo
------|--------
1     | 2
2     | 11
3     | 3
3     | 6
3     | 7
4     | 4
4     | 8
4     | 10
5     | 5
5     | 9
```

The following two queries achieve the individual parts, but I need it returned as one query set of results.

```
SELECT campaigntitle, COUNT (CAMPAIGNTITLE) As [count]
FROM WORKSON
GROUP BY CAMPAIGNTITLE
HAVING COUNT(CAMPAIGNTITLE) >2

SELECT STAFFNO, GRADE
FROM STAFFONGRADE
WHERE GRADE > 2
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT campaigntitle, StaffNo, COUNT (CAMPAIGNTITLE) As [count]
  FROM WORKSON
 WHERE StaffNo IN
       (SELECT STAFFNO
          FROM STAFFONGRADE
         WHERE GRADE > 2)
 GROUP BY CAMPAIGNTITLE
HAVING COUNT(CAMPAIGNTITLE) >2
```